# Android CheckBox set hyperlink text color

Tags: java, android, html, css, xml

I have a CheckBox that has two links in the text.

I set the text by:

```
String htmlText = "Accept <a href='someUrl'>Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href='anotherUrl'>Privacy Policy</a>";

checkbox.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
checkbox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This works perfectly accept that the  links text is white and my apps background color is white so the link text is not visible but the gaps are still there and when the gaps are clicked it opens the browser.

How do I change the text color of the links?

I have tried:

```
String htmlText = "Accept <a style='color:#007CC2;' href='someUrl'>Terms and Conditions</a> and <a style='color:#007CC2;' href='anotherUrl'>Privacy Policy</a>";
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated :).

Comment: there is very little code but try to  separate the style.                                                    <style>
a {
  color: red;
}
</style>
String htmlText = "Accept <a style='color:#;' href='someUrl'>Terms and Conditions</a> and <a ;' href='anotherUrl'>Privacy Policy</a>";

Comment: @WeyersdeLange that doesn't work. Just displays the style in the text.

Comment: I am sorry I tried to simulate your problem but on my side the style changed the color of the text that form the link.      :-(      why not style border around the link and fill the box with a light grey and round corners?

Comment: @WeyersdeLange do I do your last comment in my styles.xml file?

Comment: Or add this to your xml file to change background color.                                                                                                                          
    <color name="text" paletteColor="black" /> 
  <color name="textDisabled" paletteColor="gray.dark" /> 
  <color name="textError" paletteColor="black" /> 
  <color name="background" paletteColor="gray" /> 
  <color name="anchor" paletteColor="hyperlink" /> 
  <color name="selection" paletteColor="special1" /> 
  <color name="tooltip" paletteColor="tooltip" />

Answer (score 0):

Or try styling the check box area and not the HTML area

```css
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">CHECKEDHIGHLIGHTCOLOR</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">UNCHECKEDCOLOR</item>
</style>
```

```html
<CheckBox
     android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
     android:id="@+id/chooseItemCheckBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

code provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4224901/amro-elaswar

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere"